How can I setup ClamAV on Kubernetes cluster as a daemon set?
How can I setup ClamAV on Kubernetes cluster as a daemon set,schedule scans and store scan results ?
https://starkandwayne.com/blog/managing-your-kubernetes-cluster-with-daemonsets/
Followed these steps in this article.
Clamd pods are running but it is not triggering scans on the mentioned directories.
